# How can I redirect to a controller method passing a parameter when another controller method end its execution in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem.

I have this controller method named **dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca()**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca(@RequestParam String prgPro, Locale locale, Model model) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INTO dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca(), codice progetto: " + prgPro);

.....................................................................
.....................................................................
DO SOMETHING
.....................................................................

return "visualizzaProspetto/prospettoRendicontazione";
}
```

that as you can see handle GET request toward the  **/dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca** resource haivng a **String prgPro** passed parameter.

Then I have this other controller method named **confermaVariazioneAnticipo():

```
@RequestMapping(value = "confermaVariazioneAnticipo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String confermaVariazioneAnticipo(@RequestParam String codiceProgetto, @RequestParam String variazioneAnticipoImp, Model model) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("INTO confermaVariazioneAnticipo()");

    ..................................................................
    ..................................................................
    DO SOME OTHER THING
    ..................................................................
    ..................................................................

    REDIRECT TO THE dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca() METHOD PASSING codiceProgetto AS PARAMETER
}
```

As you can see this method handle Http GET request toward the **confermaVariazioneAnticipo** and take the **String codiceProgetto** (that is the same **prgPro** String take as parameter of the first **dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca()** method.

At the end this second method should not return the logical name of a view but have to redirect to the first **dettaglioProgettoDaRicerca()** method passing to it the **codiceProgetto** value as parameter.

How can I correctly implement this behavior?

Comment: also, check this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it as a parameter:

```
return "redirect:/path/to/other/controller?param=" + value;
```